# Anylogic queue priority

Tags: queue, priority-queue, anylogic

I have 4 agents in my queue. I have assigned a priority to each agent in the queue
e.g. children.priority = 1;
e.g. adult.priority = 2;

However when I run it I get an error. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: you will need to share a few more details, seriously :-) What error? What investigations did you do yourself?

Comment: You have to show us your code, or explain in a lot more detail what you're doing. What you've written is not enough information for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that instead of `children.priority` or `adult.priority`, you should write `agent.priority`

Or if you have in your queue agents of multiple types you could do:

```
if(agent instanceof Children)
    agent.priority=1;
else if(agent instanceof Adult)
    agent.priority=2;
```

Try that and maybe it works... I'm just guessing considering the extremely low quality of the question.